# Can we use xmlhttp.open(); in same file

Tags: php, ajax

I try to use these code from w3school but I have some problems.

My first file:

```
    <script>
    function showHint(str)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

  <?php
   echo "First name: <input type=\"text\" id=\"txt1\" onkeyup=\"showHint(this.value)\" />";
   echo "<p>Suggestions: <span id=\"txtHint\"></span></p>";
  ?>
```

My second file [getresult.php]:

```
<?php
  $a[]="Anna";
  $a[]="Brittany";
  $a[]="Cinderella";
  $a[]="Diana";

  // get the q parameter from URL
  $q=$_REQUEST["q"]; $hint="";

  // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
  if ($q !== "")
    { 
      foreach($a as $key=>$name)
        { 
          if ($q==$key)
          { 
            if ($hint==="")
          { 
            $hint=$name; 
          }
          else
            {
             $hint .= ", $name"; 
           }
        }
      }
    }

  // Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
  // or output the correct values 
  echo $hint==="" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
  ?>
```

if i want to have 1 file how should i do with

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.php?q="+str,true);
```

because I upload both file on my server it not work but i works when i run on my computer(localhost)

thanks.

Comment: What didn't work ? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    //getresult.php contents
}
else {
    //first file contents
}
```